# Windows 7 system rating or Windows experience index freeze

Tags: windows, windows-experience-index

Very similar case.. The Wei runs and stuck forever at ACCESSING CPU PERFORMANCE status in w7, and I have to forcely shutdown and restart the laptop through the button.

I have already reformatted and reinstall w7 more than 3 times and do all necessary updates. Still then, Wei stucks or freeze at the same location. Why??? Please I'm desperately disappointed now[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1rZ7.jpg)

Comment: Then stop running it, it is a bogus rating system anyway.

Comment: Do you have Direct-X (DX-DIAG) installed? You need that for Experience to run properly. It runs properly here.

Comment: There was a reason this dummy rating was removed from Windows starting from Windows 8.1.

Comment: Run the winsat mem and CPU tests separately at cmd prompt, still I can't compete the assessment process and it always stuck. The rest disk, graphic, etc test are all well completed. Just found memory assessment issues.